# PHP insert data using mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm a newbie in PHP I just studied a while ago. I made some form that on submit, it will insert new data in mysql table. I can't seem to figure out the problem. Here's my code:

```
<form method="post">
        <table border='2' cellpadding=4 cellspacing=1 width=50% bgcolor=white align=center >
        <br>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Master No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="master_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Alacarte No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="alacarte_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Dessert No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="dessert_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Pasta No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="pasta_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Rice No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="rice_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Wine No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="wine_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Member ID:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="member_id" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="td-center">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"/>
                    <input type="Reset"/>
                    <a href="member-profile.php">
                        <input type="button" name="home" value="home"/>
                    </a><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php   

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
                 if (!$conn)
                {
                 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                mysql_select_db("thesis_sofitel", $conn);

                $master_no=$_POST['master_no'] ;
                $alacarte_no= $_POST['alacarte_no'] ;   
                $dessert_no= $_POST['dessert_no'] ;
                $pasta_no= $_POST['pasta_no'] ; 
                $rice_no= $_POST['rice_no'] ;
                $wine_no= $_POST['wine_no'] ;   
                $member_id= $_POST['member_id'] ;

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `master_list`(master_no,alacarte_no,dessert_no,pasta_no,rice_no,wine_no,member_id) 
                            VALUES ('$master_no','$alacarte_no','$dessert_no','$pasta_no','$rice_no','$wine_no','$member_id')"); 

                $message = "I was here!!!";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

            }           
        ?>
    </form>
```

Comment: Since you just started, it would be so much better to start off either `mysqli` or `PDO` and stop using the _deprecated_ mysql functions. enable error reporting to know where you're messing up.

Comment: what @HawasKaPujaari says and please update your question with any errors that you see

Comment: Close your `</form>` tag right after `</table>` and move the php above the HTML.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari I did that, and it still doesn't save.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari bhai it is stackoverflow.com not antarvasna.com you should consider changing username :-)

Comment: @ddw147 jaani, as long as what I do is _within_ the rules defined in the SO and is related to the core subject of the site, which is _to learn and to help_ I don't think anyone should have any objection over my name and besides acha he to hai `;-)`

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari i dont have any objection. but it was unexpected here and i laughed when i saw it.n any way have a fun :-)

Comment: @ddw147 That is the whole point of it brother, _to let people have a good laugh_ `;-)` cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed a few bugs in your code and changed it to `mysqli`. This should work now:

**1)** provide a `action` attribute in your form, in your case `action = ""`.

**2)** `echo` the values to know if they're really being fetched. This is still prone to SQL Injection though. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to know about why/how prepared statements help.

```
<?php   
    if (isset($_POST['add-submit'])) {
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","your_pass_here","thesis_sofitel");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }

        echo        $master_no=$_POST['master_no'] ;
        echo        $alacarte_no= $_POST['alacarte_no'] ;   
        echo        $dessert_no= $_POST['dessert_no'] ;
        echo        $pasta_no= $_POST['pasta_no'] ; 
        echo        $rice_no= $_POST['rice_no'] ;
        echo        $wine_no= $_POST['wine_no'] ;   
        echo        $member_id= $_POST['member_id'] ;

$success = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `master_list`(master_no,alacarte_no,dessert_no,pasta_no,rice_no,wine_no,member_id) 
                            VALUES ('$master_no','$alacarte_no','$dessert_no','$pasta_no','$rice_no','$wine_no','$member_id')");

                            if($success){
                $message = "I was here!!!";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
                            }
                            else
                                echo "Query Failed.";

mysqli_close($con);

            }           
        ?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action = "">
        <table border='2' cellpadding=4 cellspacing=1 width=50% bgcolor=white align=center >
        <br>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Master No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="master_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Alacarte No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="alacarte_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Dessert No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="dessert_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Pasta No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="pasta_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Rice No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="rice_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Wine No.:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="wine_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font face=rockwell font size=5 font color=black>Member ID:</td>
                <td class="td-center"><input type="text" name="member_id" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="td-center">
                    <input type="submit" name="add-submit" value="Add"/>
                    <input type="Reset"/>
                    <a href="member-profile.php">
                        <input type="button" name="home" value="home"/>
                    </a><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
```

**EDIT:**

The above code works and to clarify it, I tested it myself. Below are the pictures attached.

[image: The main page]

[image: After submitting the form]

[image: The results in the database]

**SECOND EDIT:**

To show OP that if he had changed the column to `INT` type, it would still work:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @HawasKaPujaari, however when I click save, nothing happens, no error on inspect element and it still doesn't insert on mySQL.

Comment: I forgot to change the name to "add-submit". Now there's an error: "78788787878787Query Failed." Where 78788 etc. is the number inputs.

Comment: @user3545006 it means the _query failed_ `echo` the query and what do you see? match the column names with the ones in your database. (remember they are case sensitive)

Comment: all column names match in the database though. is it because the fields are in INT type?

Comment: @user3545006 that should not make any difference as I just changed one of the column type and tested it again. works fine. check the second edit to see the table structure `;-)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @HawasKaPujaari! I just figured out the error. The database has a relationship to other tables and because of that, I need to input the same value.

Comment: @user3545006 Ahh, I am glad you did. Go and do something more amazing now, best of luck `;-)` cheers